# JavaScript regex with positive lookbehind emulation

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I am trying to create a regex that will extract the bold portion from a Flickr URL.

I want the string between `www.flickr.com/photos/` and `/`.

```
https://www.flickr.com/photos/annaheimkreiter/14785981533/in/explore-2014-07-28
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have looked at various answers here and have not been able to adapt them to this aim.

Comment: I changed the formatting to make this easier to read, but I didn't try to fix the inconsistency between the question and the example.  What do you want to do about the `photos/` directory?

Comment: I corrected the mistake. IT should be www.flickr.com/photos/

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var s = 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/annaheimkreiter/14785981533/in/explore-2014-07-28';
var t;
if (m=s.match(/\/photos\/([^\/]+)/))
   t=m[1];
//=> annaheimkreiter
```

Comment: +1, a capture group is the way to go. Maybe the downvote is because it's not 100% clear from the question that `annaheimkreiter` is what CodeToad wants: on the one hand it is in bold; on the other hand he says he wants the string after `.com`, which would be `photos`. (In that case Code Toad it's a tiny tweak to anubhava's regex: `m=s.match(/\/flickr\.com\/([^/]+)/)`)

Comment: I agree that there's no call for lookbehind here (emulated or otherwise), but you should have included a comment to that effect in the answer.  Also, don't you need to escape the slash in `[^/]`?.  It's the regex delimiter, not a regex metacharacter.

Comment: Actually inside the character class it doesn't need escaping. I tested on Chrome. But may be some older browsers may complain that's why I edited it.

Comment: This is close.  see here: http://regexr.com/3983a  I want the result to be only 'annaheimkreiter'

Comment: Yes result is indeed just `annaheimkreiter` using code I showed above.'

Comment: [See this demo](http://regex101.com/r/yT8qY2/2) and your text is in the bottom-right `MATCH INFORMATION`